# Why my functional component doesn't re-render when change state? (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, rerender

I'm stuck in project because my functional component do not re-render when I update this state.

```
const OneProduct = (props) => {
return (
<div className='productincart'>
    <div className='name'>{props.name}</div> 
    <div className='price'>Price: {props.price}</div>
    <div className='quantity'>{props.quantity}</div>
</div>)
}

const InsideCart = (props) => {
    const cartTemporary = props.sendCart
    const [cart, setCart] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        setCart(cartTemporary)
        }, [cartTemporary])

    const showCart = () => {
        console.log(cart)
    }

    return (

        <div className='insidecart'>
            {cart.map(product => <OneProduct name={product.name} price= 
            {product.price} quantity={product.quantity} key={uniqid()} />)}
            <button onClick={showCart}>SHOW CART</button>
        </div>
    )
    }
```

In code above, I putting products from shop to the `cart`, next I want to display it on the screen. When I'm putting new item to the `cart` (new object in `cart` array), everything works fine. When I'm only update quantity of object already exist in cart array, nothing happens. After quantity updating, `cart` is updated with new value, but it doesn't causing re-render of component.

That is problem to solve, how to make component re-render after quantity value update.

Below format of objects which I add to `cart`, also added mechanism of adding and increasing quantity.

```
const Products = (props) => {
    const initialProducts = [
        { id: 0, name: "Fish - Betta splendens - Plakat Koi - Siamese fighting fish", image: image0, price: 23.17, quantity: 1 },
        { id: 1, name: "Fish - Betta splendens - Plakat - Siamese fighting fish", image: image1, price: 10.12, quantity: 1 },
        { id: 2, name: "Fish - Phenacogrammus interruptus - Congo tetra", image: image2, price: 5.19, quantity: 1 },
        { id: 3, name: "Fish - Thayeria boehlkei - Pinguin tetra", image: image3, price: 1.31, quantity: 1 },
        { id: 4, name: "Fish - Pterophyllum scalare - Angelfish", image: image4, price: 5.77, quantity: 1 },
        { id: 5, name: "Fish - Boeseman's rainbowfish Melanotaenia - Boesemani", image: image5, price: 4.90, quantity: 1 },
        { id: 6, name: "Fish - Ram cichlid - Mikrogeophagus ramirezi", image: image6, price: 4.61, quantity: 1 },
        { id: 7, name: "Fish - Corydoras aeneus sp.black venezuela", image: image7, price: 2.87, quantity: 1 },

    ]
    const [products, setProducts] = useState(initialProducts)
    const [toCart, setToCart] = useState([])

    const getProductId = (e) => {
        const idString = e.target.dataset.id
        const id = Number(idString)
        return id
    }

    const getProductById = (e) => {
        const id = getProductId(e)
        const itemFound = products.find(product => product.id === id)
        const foundedOrNot = toCart.find(product => product === itemFound)
        if (foundedOrNot === undefined) {
            setToCart([...toCart, itemFound])
        }
        else {
            const index = toCart.findIndex(product => product === itemFound)
            toCart[index].quantity = toCart[index].quantity + 1
        }

    }

    return (
        <div className="products">
            <Nav sendToCart={toCart} />
            <InsideCart sendCart={toCart} />
            <div className='container'>{products.map((product) => <Product onClick={getProductById} title={product.name} img={product.image} price={product.price} id={product.id} key={product.id} />)}</div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Also add simple component which determines rendering what is inside the cart.

```
const OneProduct = (props) => {
    return (<div className='productincart'><div className='name'>{props.name}</div> <div className='price'>Price: {props.price}</div><div className='quantity'>{props.quantity}</div></div>)
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you update the cart? My guess is that you're updating by reference, instead of calling `setCart` with a new value.

Comment: I don't see where you update the cart.

Comment: I just flicked through your code and failed to spot any code that actually performs "add to basket" operation. I might suspect, though, you're using `Array.prototype.push()` or `Array.prototype.splice()` method for that and since they mutate arrays in place, React fails to figure out that state has been modified.

Comment: So, most likely, you would want to make state updates immutable by shallow copying initial array, modifying that and then setting your state to updated array.

Comment: And, just a side note, generating `uniqid()` for your `key` is definitely not a good idea from a performance standpoint. I would recommend sticking to product `id` as a key.

Comment: Already added code of component which is responsible for adding product to cart. Thanks for note about the `uniqid()`. Just starting with React :)

Comment: Both `product` and `itemFound` seem to be objects. And you can't compare objects with strict equivalence operator (`===`), hence it looks like you never actually update your state.

Comment: If you need to find out whether the item exists within an array, I would suggest [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). It will return boolean, so you won't get distracted by types mismatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved the problem. Issue was not using `setToCart` in `product` component. Thank you guys for all advices!

Updated code below:

```
  const getProductById = (e) => {
        const id = getProductId(e)
        const itemFound = products.find(product => product.id === id)
        const foundedOrNot = toCart.some(product => product === itemFound)
        if (foundedOrNot === false) {
            setToCart([...toCart, itemFound])
        }
        else {
            const index = toCart.findIndex(product => product === itemFound)
            const newCart = toCart.map(cart => {
                if (cart.id === index) {
                    cart.quantity = cart.quantity + 1
                    return cart
                }
                return cart
            })
            setToCart(newCart)
        }

    }
```

Comment: You're still doing the same mistake (`product === itemFound` will always returrn `false`), so you will never enter your `else` branch. You're supposed to compare product objects by `id` (`product.id === itemFound.id`) within `some()`.

Comment: Thank you for advice. I will change it in code to write it better.
Otherwise, I can't agree `product === itemFound` will always return `false`, because in this case it really return `true`. 
Of course I realize that, it is bad practice and should be not used.

Comment: It's not a matter of good or bad practice, it's just the way [strict equality operator works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality#comparing_objects). In your particular case it may currently return `true` due to the fact that the reference to original objects is preserved but it may lead to some nasty bags in the future.